# How is this asymptotic expansion of an integral calculated?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implementation-details, asymptotics

I am strongly impressed by this example from [New in 13](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/new-in-13-symbolic-numeric-computation/)

```
as = 
  AsymptoticIntegrate[
    (t^10 + 3) Exp[I λ (t^5 + t + 1)], 
    {t, -2, 2}, {λ, Infinity, 2}
  ]
```

> `(250400/(531441 λ^2) + (1027 I)/(81 λ)) Cos[33 λ] + (250400/(531441 λ^2) - (1027 I)/(81 λ)) Cos[35 λ] + (-((250400 I)/(531441 λ^2)) + 1027/(81 λ)) Sin[33 λ] + ((250400 I)/(531441 λ^2) + 1027/(81 λ)) Sin[35 λ]`

Indeed,

```
N[as /. λ -> 20]
```

> `0.511368 + 1.14401 I`

is in a good accordance with

```
NIntegrate[
  (t^10 + 3) Exp[I*λ (t^5 + t + 1)] /. λ -> 20, 
  {t, -2, 2}
]
```

> `0.511551 + 1.14442 I`

I am interested how `AsymptoticIntegrate` derives it. Usually the command works as `Series@Integrate`, but in the case under consideration

```
Integrate[
  (t^10 + 3) Exp[I*λ (t^5 + t + 1)], 
  {t, -2, 2},
  Assumptions -> λ > 0
]
```

fails and returns the input.

Is the Laplace method (with generalizations) really implemented in Mathematica? I clearly understand that this is proprietary knowledge of Wolfram Research Inc, but I hope to see a general answer; I do not expect implementation details.

Comment: Unfortunately, 13.0 fails with  `AsymptoticIntegrate[t^-t*t^x, {t, 0, Infinity}, {x, Infinity, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> x > 0]`.

Comment: **Fails** because for integral: `Integrate[t^-t, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]`  closed form solution **Not** exist yet.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Did you carefully  read my question before having posted your comment? Version 13.0 fails with `Integrate[(t^10 + 3) Exp[I*\[Lambda] (t^5 + t + 1)], {t, -2, 2}, Assumptions -> \[Lambda] > 0]`, but `AsymptoticIntegrate` cracks it as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: The integral $$ \int_0^\infty t^{-t}t^x\,dt$$ is  known to be a test example for Laplace's method. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 Sin[t]/t* Exp[I \[Lambda] (t^5 + t + 1)], {t, -2, 2}, {\[Lambda], 
  Infinity, 1}]` fails in a long time, though `Integrate[Sin[t]/t,{t,-2,2}]` is expressed through special functions.

Comment: @MarcoB: I have never seen the "asymptotic integral" notion which you wrote in the title  in your edit. Can you give a reference? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. My play with modifications of the example under consideration,
e.g.

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[(t^2 + 2)*Sinh[t]*Cos[2 t]* 
Exp[I \[Lambda] (t^12 + 2*t + 1)], {t, -2, Infinity}, {\[Lambda],Infinity, 1}]
```

> `-(((2 + 1/6^(2/11)) E^((I \[Pi])/4 +  I (1 - 2^(10/11)/3^(1/11) + 1/(6 6^(1/11))) \[Lambda]) Sqrt[\[Pi]/ 11] Cos[2^(10/11)/3^(1/11)] Sinh[1/6^(1/11)])/( 6^(1/22) Sqrt[\[Lambda]]))`

and

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[(t^2 + 2)*Sinh[t]*Cos[2 t]*
Exp[I \[Lambda] (Pi*t^12 + 2*t + 1)], {t, -2, 5}, {\[Lambda],Infinity, 3}]
```

which output is too long to be quoted here,

suggests that the asymptitic expansion for the integral $$\int\limits_a^b Q(t)e^{i\lambda P(t)}\,dt $$ as $\lambda \to \infty$,
where $Q(t)$ is a quasi-polynomial over the reals (see [Russian edition of Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD)
which is better on this topic than English one) and $P(t)$ is a polynomial over the reals and the range of the integration may be infinite,
is currently implemented in Mathematica. This is a special case of the [method of stationary phase](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stationary_phase,_method_of_the).